# Firebird to firebase realtime sync

Tags: firebase, firebird, firebase-realtime-database, firebird2.1

I have a Firebird database. I am trying to make real-time data transfer to Firebase. Is this possible? Any idea?

```
Firebird version : Firebird-2.1.5
```

Comment: Given that we're talking about software, it is probably possible. How to implement it depends a lot on your use-case. Unless you make the question a lot more concrete (and show what you've tried already), I vote that this is too broad to answer here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: hey thank you for reply , i dont know anything about firebird .I think maybe stackoverflow people help me my english is very bad.So i wrote short my problem.

Comment: Try this: http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq249/

Answer (score 0):

In 2006 I create a process to replicate all data from Firebird to SQL Server.

I created 3 triggers for every table (for INSERT UPDATE DELETE) that generate and store the insert, update and delete scripts in a table.

With a job in SQL Server those scripts were run (every 5 minutes) in order to have SQL Server backup database updated.

I used SQL Server data to generate reports and queries without impact production database in Firbird.

I also used the same stored data to replicate info to a backup Firebird db located in another city for business continuity.